# Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception: NoSuchMethodError: org.spring..xyz..userdetails.User.withUsername(String)

Tags: jhipster

Created two JHipster projects, namely account-service and api-gateway. Also downloaded JHipster Registry project from https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry. And imported each maven/gradle project in Eclipse.

I am new to Spring Cloud Config, so wanted to test the current generated source from JHipster, without modifying any source. But failed to execute the microservice project due to error.

Firstly I started Jhipster Registry, which is up and running at 8761. Next I started api-gateway, which is also up at port 8765, and able to see the same listed in Instances Registered in Jhipster Registry UI.

After that I tried starting account-service at port 8081, but due to error unable to test further.

Not sure, if I need to make any changes in these generated sources, for them to start working, like some configurations or yml changes...

Following error occurs, when I try to start microservice:-

```
2017-01-17 11:53:27.538  WARN 6320 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.withUsername(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User$UserBuilder;
2017-01-17 11:53:27.597 ERROR 6320 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.withUsername(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User$UserBuilder;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1028)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at com.infosys.icets.openbank.account.AccountServiceApp.main(AccountServiceApp.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.withUsername(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User$UserBuilder;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.withUsername(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User$UserBuilder;
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.provisioning.UserDetailsManagerConfigurer$UserDetailsBuilder.username(UserDetailsManagerConfigurer.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.provisioning.UserDetailsManagerConfigurer$UserDetailsBuilder.access$200(UserDetailsManagerConfigurer.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.provisioning.UserDetailsManagerConfigurer.withUser(UserDetailsManagerConfigurer.java:72)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.AuthenticationManagerConfiguration$DefaultInMemoryUserDetailsManagerConfigurer.configure(AuthenticationManagerConfiguration.java:173)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.AuthenticationManagerConfiguration$DefaultInMemoryUserDetailsManagerConfigurer.configure(AuthenticationManagerConfiguration.java:152)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.configure(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:384)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.authenticationManager(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:262)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:195)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:315)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:86)
    at com.infosys.icets.openbank.account.config.MicroserviceSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$623972a1.init(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:371)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:325)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$96a083ad.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$3(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$96a083ad$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c0a00255.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$96a083ad.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

Please find the below `.yo-rc.json` file:-

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "jhipsterVersion": "3.12.1",
    "baseName": "AccountService",
    "packageName": "com.xyz.account",
    "packageFolder": "com/xyz/account",
    "serverPort": "8081",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "hibernateCache": "no",
    "clusteredHttpSession": false,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "searchEngine": false,
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": "eureka",
    "buildTool": "gradle",
    "enableSocialSignIn": false,
    "jwtSecretKey": "8afcc092896ceb03680141e287155a8a1f5ba035",
    "enableTranslation": false,
    "applicationType": "microservice",
    "testFrameworks": [],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "skipClient": true,
    "skipUserManagement": true,
    "clientPackageManager": "npm"
  }
}
```

Comment: Should work out of the box. Please post version of JHipster and the `.yo-rc.json`file of your micro service app.

Comment: JHipster version: `3.12.1`